# Including bin subfolders in ASP.NET Deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, msbuild

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 web-application with post-build build events that copies some interop dll's into subfolders of bin as follows

```
bin\x86\Sqlite.interop.dll 
bin\x64\Sqlite.interpo.dll
```

When I deploy this project onto the web-server, it does not copy the x86 or x64 subfolders.

How can I make the deployment copy those two sub-folders?

I've tried including the files in the project with "copy to output folder" setting, but this does not copy to a subfolder, only to bin. I need to publish both subfolders all the time.

Comment: I'd consider putting your interop DLLs into a separate folder and referencing that folder **not within the bin folder**. Convoluting the bin folder structure is only going to cause you headaches

Comment: The Sqlite ADO.NET provider looks at entry assembly execution folder (bin) and loads the right interop assembly based on x86/x64 subfolder. Just found out that IISEXPRESS does not launch from the bin folder, so the x64/x86 subfolders are useless on asp.net web apps (not so for WinForms/WPF).

Answer (score 0):

In case you have common DAL assembly you can perform a such trick:

1. Embedd native dll's to your assembly as resources
2. Create static constructor to your 'entry point' class (Session, SessionFactory, etc.) and save to FS native dll's if necessary from this constructor

Update:

Also you can add to your project all native dll's. Mark them as Content and Copy Always. In this case they will be deployed with your service

Comment: This assumes write-privilege on the bin folder, which is not the case for web apps or even desktop apps installed under "program files".

Comment: Desktop apps are permissed to write in their Program Files folder. Have you tried to add these files to your project and mark them as Content?

Comment: Modifying Program Files folder requires admin privilege. Reading does not.